# Need pointers on how to do this trigonometric proof

Tags: trigonometry

$$ \cos x = \cos y + \cos^3 y$$

$$\sin x = \sin y - \sin^3 y$$

Prove that $\sin {(x - y)} = \pm \frac{1}{3}$.

I need a little hint, not a complete answer.

Comment: Do you actually mean $\sin x - y$, or it is $\sin (x - y)$?

Comment: The second one.

Comment: Fixed that, thanks.

Comment: I'm getting different answer
$$
\sin(x-y) = \sin x \cos y - \cos x \sin y = (\sin y - \sin^3 y) \cos y - (\cos y + \cos^3 y) \sin y = \\
= -\sin^3 y \cos y - \cos^3 y \sin y = -\sin y \cos y(\sin^2 + \cos^2 y) = -\sin y \cos y
$$

Comment: Actually, never mind, it can be simplified further.

Comment: I think the identity is wrong.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal,I had same result. cos2y have $\sqrt{13}$ factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:  here $\sin x=\sin y(1-\sin^2y)=\sin y\cos^2y$

$\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1\implies \sin^2y\cos^4y+\cos^2y+\cos^6y+2\cos^4y=1$

$\implies (1-\cos^2y)\cos^4y+\cos^2y+\cos^6y+2\cos^4y=1$

$\implies 3\cos^4y+\cos^2y-1=0$

EDIT:

Subs. $\cos^2y = t$ gives $3t^2+t-1=0\implies t=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{13}}{6}\tag{taking positive root only}$

$\implies \cos^2y=\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{13}}{6}\implies \sin^2y=1-\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{13}}{6}=\dfrac{7-\sqrt{13}}{6}$

Therefore, $\sin^2(x-y)=\sin^2y\cos^2y=\left(\dfrac{7-\sqrt{13}}{6}\right)\left(\dfrac{-1+\sqrt{13}}{6}\right)=\dfrac{8\sqrt{13}-20}{36}\neq\dfrac{1}{9}$

Therefore, $\sin(x-y)\neq\pm\dfrac{1}{3}$

I think there is some problem with your question or the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

We have, $\cos x-\cos y=\cos^3y$ and  $\sin x-\sin y=-\sin^3y$

Squaring & adding we get
$$2-2\cos(x-y)=\cos^6 y+\sin^6 y=(\cos^2y+\sin^2y)^3-3(\cos^2y\sin^2y)(\cos^2y+\sin^2y)=1-3\cos^2y\sin^2y$$

$$\implies\cos(x-y)=\frac{1+3\cos^2y\sin^2y}2=\frac{4+3(2\sin y\cos y)^2}8=\frac{4+3\sin^22y}8=\frac{7-3\cos^22y}8\ \ \ \ (1)$$

Again, $$\cos(x-y)=\cos x\cos y+\sin x\sin y$$

$$=(\cos y+\cos^3y)\cos y+(\sin y-\sin^3y)\sin y$$

$$=1+\cos^4y-\sin^4y=1+(\cos^2y+\sin^2y)(\cos^2y+\sin^2y)=1+\cos2y\ \ \ \ (2)$$

Comparing $(1),(2)$
 $$1+\cos2y=\frac{7-3\cos^22y}8\iff 3\cos^22y+\cos2y+1=0$$

$$\implies \cos2y=\frac{-8\pm\sqrt{8^2-4\cdot3\cdot1}}{2\cdot3}=\frac{-4\pm\sqrt{13}}3$$

Now, $4>\sqrt{13}>3\implies -\frac{4+\sqrt{13}}3>-2$

As for real $y,-1\le \cos2y\le1,\cos2y=\frac{-4+\sqrt{13}}3$

$$\implies \cos(x-y)=1+\cos2y=1+\frac{-4+\sqrt{13}}3=\frac{-1+\sqrt{13}}3$$

$$\implies\sin(x-y)=\pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2(x-y)} $$

Comment: @chenabi, did you reach here, or I have made something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the identity is wrong, since

Multiplying the first equation by $-\sin y$ gives
$$ \cos x = \cos y + \cos^3 y \implies -\cos x\sin y=-\sin y \cos y - \sin y \cos^3 y $$
Multiplying the second equation by $\cos y$ gives

$$  \sin x = \sin y - \sin^3 y \implies \sin x\cos y  = \sin y \cos y - \cos y \sin^3 y  $$

adding the two equations gives

$$ \sin(x-y) = -\sin y\cos y ( \sin^2 y+\cos^2 y ) \implies \sin(x-y)= -\frac{\sin(2y)}{2}. $$